# How to Free Up Disk Space without using a Command Line?

Tags: updates, update-manager, disk-management

**I need to free space on my disk to update my computer.**

I ran the update manager and it said I did not have enough space to update, I needed ~1,124 M to update. I checked around on *Ask Ubuntu* and everyone, basically, suggested running the "*get clean*" command and a few others. I *can not* run the "*get clean*" command because I do not have my root password and attempts at retrieving it have been unsuccessful.

Is there some other way to clear up space for the update? One that is "safe" to use? By safe, I mean a way that's user friendly for those who don't have a good understanding of command lines.

Comment: I recommend to just reset the password ([How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/q/24006/507051)) and use `sudo apt clean`.

Comment: Clearing up space will mean removing some root files so without root password, nothing will happen!

Comment: Will resorting to an old "backup" potentially solve my problems?

Comment: Restoring from an old backup seems a convoluted way to simply delay the day of reckoning: The day you must reset the password. It's not difficult.

Comment: I've tried using established methods to fix my problem with the root password; however, I don't have the option of recovery - which is essential for the reseting of root passwords.